# VCL Components Delphi

Tags: delphi, vcl

What VCL component shows data faster? For example, if I want to read a file and write it to the data in tabular form. Something like TStringGrid or TListView. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the Virtual Tree View? It's not built-in, it's a third-party control, but it's very commonly used for performance. Which Delphi version?

Comment: I use TStringGrid It faster then TListView

Comment: @Jerry That's virtual tree view. TListView in virtual mode is a standard common control, the system standard list control.

Comment: Yes, the Virtual Tree View rather. OP asked question last night on this topic about speed of `TListView` with tens of thousands of items.

Comment: @NikitaZakharov Did you mean to comment on David's answer? David is suggesting you switch your existing `TListView` control to virtual mode, which is in turn faster than a grid.

Comment: @Jerry In spite of what so many people said there, virtual list view is blazingly fast when used properly. In virtual mode.

Comment: @Nikita TListView is faster when you use it correctly. In virtual mode. Please don't change the question to ask how to use virtual mode. Start with the many questions on this site, and the good examples provided by Embarcadero.

Comment: Common list view is far behind what Virtual Treeview offers. You can use it for list view, tree view or grid view. I would personally suggest Virtual Treeview as well.

Comment: @TLama It you want a list then I don't see what advantage you have with vtt. Advantage of system control is that it is system native.

Comment: Hence the reason I voted to close this question as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Jerry Which is faster is hardly opinion based. But the question as it stands is very poor. I'd opt for "unclear what you are asking". The question could easily be fixed. "Which of these two controls performs better with large amounts of data?"

Comment: @David, I see no benefit of using native controls for those which VTV can replace (VTV can render by theme and has UI automation access; the rest about nativeness I don't care). Writing data adapters for one control is easier than for many. But the best on VTV is its flexibility. Many native controls that VTV can replace can only dream about ways how can be configured.

Comment: @TLama Flexibility is great. But what if you don't need it? And as for drawing themed, that's fine until the new os version that changes things. IIRC vtt didn't use theme api for some considerable time after its introduction. I think vtt is great though. I'm not dissing it at all.

Comment: Problem is, we don't know if OP needs it or not.

Answer (score 3):

Virtual mode list view has better performance that a VCL grid for very large amounts of data.

To be clear though, you must use the control in virtual mode. In standard mode (control stores the entire content) the performance is terrible for large amounts of data.

Even beyond the issue of performance, virtual mode is to be preferred. Using virtual mode allows you to decouple the data storage from the UI presentation.